# MySQL 5.7 do math with column and a MAX() value

Tags: mysql, sql, azerothcore

I have a temp table with a column enumerated from 1. I would like to get the MAX() value of a column in another table and add it to all columns in the temp table. I tried it with a variable like this:

```
SET @cc_maxguid = SELECT MAX(guid) FROM item_instance;
UPDATE tempItems SET guid = guid + @cc_maxguid WHERE owner_guid = '..targetGUID..';
```

While targetGUID is added from a variabl of the LUA script.
The response is: `Error Code: 1064. You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'SELECT MAX(guid) FROM item_instance' at line 1`

So basically e.g. this `tempItems` table

```
guid  A  B
  1   5  6
  2   4  7 
  3   3  8
```

with a MAX(guid) value of 20 from `item_instance` should become

```
guid   A  B
 21    5  6
 22    4  7 
 23    3  8
```

How can i adjust my query to make it request and add the MAX(guid) value?

Comment: If you enclose `SELECT MAX(guid) FROM item_instance` inside parentheses your code works fine. Is this your actual code? What is the table `'characters'`?

Comment: the only place I see the `characters` table is in your error message, but in any case, the error message is pretty explicit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This error occurs when you are trying to update a table in MySQL and used the same table in your update critera.

```
SET @cc_maxguid = (SELECT MAX(guid) FROM item_instance);
UPDATE tempItems SET guid = guid + @cc_maxguid WHERE owner_guid = '..targetGUID..';
```

Above query should run fine. Please let me know if there is another part of the query which you didn't share.